# Cannot use object of type stdClass as array with select box

Tags: php

I can use the following code below and it works perfectly and populates the select box as expected.

```
<select id="eventtype">
  <?php
    foreach($data['EventType'] as $data)
    {
      if($admin){
        if($data->Available == "1"){
          echo '<option value="'.$data->Event_Type.'">'.$data->Event_Type.' (Available)'.'</option>';
        }
        if($data->Available == "0"){
          echo '<option value="'.$data->Event_Type.'">'.$data->Event_Type.' (UnAvailable)'.'</option>';
        }
      }
      else{
        if($data->Available == "1"){
          echo '<option value="'.$data->Event_Type.'">'.$data->Event_Type.'</option>';
        }
      }
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

But, as soon as I add another box (copy paste) it breaks the rest of my code and I get the error:

> Cannot use object of type stdClass as array with select box

Comment: Please show the code that breaks? I'm not clear on what you mean!

Comment: So pretty much this works...
<?php
 foreach($data['EventType'] as $data){
  echo $data->ID;
 }
?>

this gives me that error
<?php
 foreach($data['EventType'] as $data){
  echo $data->ID;
 }
 foreach($data['EventType'] as $data){
  echo $data->ID;
 }
?>

Comment: What is meant by "that error"?

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in * on line *

Comment: Think I see the problem. On a style note, I prefer a bit more whitespace in code (e.g. around operators, after control statements, before open braces), and to entirely separate PHP and HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Ah! It's getting confused because you have an array AND a loop variable called $data. Try using different names!

```
<select id="eventtype">
  <?php
    foreach($data['EventType'] as $type)
    {
        if($admin){
            if($type->Available=="1"){
                echo '<option value="'.$type->Event_Type.'">'.$type->Event_Type.' (Available)'.'</option>';
            }
            if($type->Available=="0"){
                echo '<option value="'.$type->Event_Type.'">'.$type->Event_Type.' (UnAvailable)'.'</option>';
            }
        }
        else{
            if($type->Available=="1"){
                echo '<option value="'.$type->Event_Type.'">'.$type->Event_Type.'</option>';
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Oh my goodness i cant believe it was that simple, thank you for your help! much appreciated.